# What is the music at season 3 episode 18 when Yuga Aoyama was distracting the enemy?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What is the music at season 3 episode 18 of *My Hero Academia* at 19:00 when Yuga Aoyama was distracting the enemy?

Answer (score -2):

'Surpassing You' or 'Ochaco' from 3rd ost